# jquery mobile update innerHTML not rendering

Tags: jquery, mobile, refresh, render, innerhtml

I'm just beginning to use Jquery. I'm placing some jquery code that is generated dynamically by a javascript function into a div using innerHTML. It is not rendering the jquery look/style of it. I know the jquery code being generated is correct because it looks fine if I paste it in manually and restart the page.

Do I have to somehow update the page or refresh the rendering using a Jquery command after loading new content dynamically into innerHTML?

I also tried what I think is the jquery version of innerHTML but it does the same thing.

```
$("#propchoices").html(data);
```

Comment: You generate jQuery code by javascript? What is the point? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is part of an iphone app that uploads content to a local file periodically. It then loads data from that file locally, parses it up into a list of radio button choices that are written dynamically to a div.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to refresh the page after inserting into your document..

Make sure you enclose your code inside DOM Ready event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Your Dynamic Data Here

    $("#propchoices").html(data);

});
```

Comment: The dynamic html is written after the page has loaded on the click of a button by the user. So document.ready is true at that point. Using document.ready didn't help, it still does not render correctly when inserted dynamically. When does jquery render content? Only at the beginning or continuously. If I rewrite a big section of a div don't I have to tell jquery to re-render the page.

Comment: Is the button being populated dynamically

Comment: No, not the button. This is part of an iphone app that uploads content to a local file periodically. It then loads data from that file locally, parses it up into a list of radio button choices that are written dynamically to a div. So the radio button list is dynamic. There may be 7 choices in one case or 3 in another depending on the data that comes in.

Comment: So is the click event here, is for the Dynamically created radioListbuttons right

Comment: Yes. I've been working with dojo before, and it had to be re-rendered if new content was added with document.write or innerhtml. Is jquery the same way?

Comment: Then in that case the click event will only work for elements currently on the page.. If you want the click event's to work for newly added elements you need to delegate the event..

Comment: If you can show the click event and the parent for the Radiobuttons I can look into it